# how to redirect request in grails

Tags: grails, redirect

When I redirect to another action in the same controller the 'request' is null.

```
def updateEmployee() {
        println "updateEmployee(): request =" + request.JSON
        redirect(action: "createEmployee", params: params)
}


def createEmployee() {
    def renderStatus = 500;
    System.out.println "createEmployee() : request= " + request.JSON;
```

the updateEmployee prints all the request data, but creteEmployee prints it as null ([:])

How to redirect the 'request' (I mean the POST data ) ?

Comment: For clarification, null and an empty map are very different things.

Comment: oh! thanks @BurtBeckwith for pointing out the difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot *redirect POST request*. Redirect mean a new GET request, so all previous data from previous request will be lost.

If you need to call another action without actual redirect use `forward`: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html